# Add package reference to .net framework project using command line(in Dev Servers)

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I tried a lot to achieve this functionality by googled multiple number of web sites but not found a way to achieve this.

I want to add package reference to my .net framework project using command line , which is similar to

"dotnet add *package*"

Since the above command only works for dot core projects, but i need the same functionality for .net framework.

please help me to get some options to achieve the above functionality

Comment: Quick question: Is your goal to add a package to your project *after* it compiled and was installed on the dev servers, or are you asking how to add a package reference to your project via CLI?

Comment: I want to add a package reference to my .net framework project via CLI,  so that my developers no need to add that package into their project?

Comment: That will not be possible. If your developers don't have that package referenced in their projects, then they cannot use it. Well, they can, the project just won't compile locally because their compiler doesn't know about a certain package

Comment: The package we are adding wont effect any application functionality, it only validate code compliance checks like coverlet

Comment: And you don't want your developers to see that? Personally I'd much rather know when my code isn't compliant so I can fix it, before pushing to CI. Plus, the project being compiled on your CI should be exactly the same as on the dev machines, package references and all included

Comment: Agreed, but my developers have Visual Studio to validate that, where we dont have VS in  CI